# Delete All But The Newest File of Pattern In Each Subdirectory

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

Requirements:

1. Iterate through all folders and files in each directory
2. Delete all files in each subdirectory except for the newest one (contains filename time stamp) and has a specific filename pattern or instead copy the one file in each subdirectory that is the newest and that is preceded with LIVE_DATA. (There are other files in each subdirectory I wish to ignore).

   - **Directory:** AISI-301.0000000001006165.2015-08-24_23-57-46-1
   - **File:** LIVE_DATA_2015-08-24_23-57-51.413+0000.MCA

How can I iterate through all of the files recursively while doing comparisons between files in each subdirectory only? I don't want to compare all of them together. Just the one's inside each subdirectory.

```
for $filename in Get-ChildItem -recurse {
    for $filename in $directory {
        if ($filename > $filename2) {
            $temp = $filename
        }
        $filename2 = $filename1
    }
}
```

This is what I ended up using to rename my file's after the directory names. It appends the file name to the end and the directory name comes first. I hope this helps somebody else that might be searching for this solution.

```
    Get-ChildItem -include *LIVE_DATA_*.MCA -recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name}
```

Comment: Because your question doesn't show any effort to solve the problem yourself. The code you posted hardly has anything to do with your requirements and isn't even valid PowerShell code to begin with.

Comment: I'll be sure to be more careful in the future on my posting by giving it a better run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove all files `LIVE_DATA_*` except the most recent one on a per-folder basis you could do something like this:

```
$root = 'C:\path\to\root\folder'

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $_.FullName 'LIVE_DATA_*') |
    Sort-Object Name -Desc |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Remove-Item -Force
}
```

`Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }` lists all subfolders of `$root`. Then the `ForEach-Object` runs another `Get-ChildItem` statement (without recursion) for each subfolder separately. The `Join-Path` statement builds a wildcard path from the filename pattern and the full path to the folder (`C:\path\to\root\folder\sub\folder\LIVE_DATA_*`).

Basically the code lists all folders, then processes the files for each individual folder.

Comment: That's pretty slick. I believe, the `Sort-Object` expression only works, if the timestamp is always in the same relative position in the file name (and only a single pattern is used). Sorting by last modification timestamp may be more robust.

Comment: Correct. The code is based on the assumption that all filenames have the same structure and that the dates are provided in ISO format. Like you I would've preferred sorting based on `LastWriteTime`, but we don't know if the modification time acutally corresponds to the timestamp in the filename and I didn't want to make more assumptions than I already had to.

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Recurse # Goes through all of the files and subdirectories. .PSIsContainer means to go into a container or folder. ForEach-Object means for each subdirectory. Get-ChildItem again goes through the files. Inside each one we sort the objects by name in descending order, we skip the first one, and remove all the others. Am I correct in my interpretation? Can you explain "Join-Path $_.FullName" please?

Comment: Thank you! That helps me very much! I have one last question. If I wanted to save each subdirectories folder name up to the first "." and append it to the beginning of each LIVE_DATA file. How would I go about that? Should I do another Get-ChildItem $root | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }. Can I pipe that to a variable? How would I do that since I'm not actually iterating through each folder? I'd have to do it in one go with the Get-ChildItem class. Thanks in advance for any pointers.